# iPhone app on iPad: UILabel pixelated during rotation?

Tags: iphone, ipad, rotation, uilabel

I tried my iPhone app (not universal) on iPad 2 just for a test... and I noticed something strange.
In a view I have some `UILabel` (inside an `UIImageView`) that spin, float and collide with each other, but on iPad 2 the labels are drawn as pixelated when they rotate. I mean obviously in x1 mode. I still hadn't a chance to test on iPad 1.
I have implemented rotation and displacement with NSTimer (scheduled with time interval of 0.05). No problem with `UIImageView` objects, only with `UILabel` objects. The effect is really horrible.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: i have the same problem, when i try to rotate UILabel like this: "label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(...);", on iPad it looks horrible, but on iPhone there is no problem.

Comment: Same problem here, never found a solution. Bug in Apple's code maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while, but I'm back on this issue and I solved it by setting `shouldRasterize` for `UIView` objects transformed with `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`:

```
subview.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```